# Inconsistency in column numbers between ALTER TABLE and INSERT INTO/VALUES

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I wish to ask a question about CREATE TABLE, ALTER TABLE, UPDATE/SET/WHERE because I am thoroughly confused about how to use these commands when a PRIMARY KEY is involved, and I am getting different advice from different people. Initially, I establish a connection to the database and create a table, in a file called "creation.php":

```
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Accommodation");

      $sql="CREATE TABLE Hotels(Name CHAR(30),City CHAR(30))";
```

My second file, called "hoteldetails.php", generates a questionnaire which asks hotel guests the name of the hotel they stayed at and which city their hotel is located in. The user data from"hoteldetails.php" is processed by "processhoteldetails.php", and this file (not given in its complete form) contains the following:

```
       session_start();
       $sessionID =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " " . 
       date("Y-m-d    H:i:s",time());

       $_SESSION['sessionID']=$sessionID;


           $sql = "ALTER TABLE Hotels
           ADD COLUMN (
           `Name` VARCHAR(30),
           `City` VARCHAR(30));";

          $sql="INSERT INTO Hotels (SessionID, Name, City)
          VALUES ('$sessionID','$name', '$city')";

          if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
```

After the data is processed, the user is connected to another webpage which is generated by a file called "hotelrecommendation.php" and this webpage asks the user whether he will recommend the hotel to others and give a rating as well. "hotelrecommendation.php" is processed by "processhotelrecommendation.php" which looks like this (only a part of the code given here):

```
          session_start();

          $sessionID = $_SESSION['sessionID'];

          if($sessionID == "") {
   $sessionID =  $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . " " . date("Y-m-d H:i:s",time());
   $_SESSION['sessionID']=$sessionID;
   }

            $sql = "ALTER TABLE Hotels
            ADD COLUMN (
           `Recommendation` VARCHAR(150),
           `Rating` SMALLINT(5));";

            mysqli_query($con,$sql);

            $sql = "UPDATE Hotels
            SET  `Recommendation` = '$recommendation',
                 `Rating` = '$rating'
                  where sessionID = '$sessionID'";
```

When I answer the questions in "hoteldetails.php" and click SUBMIT, I get an error message saying "Error: Column SessionID does not exist in field list". (I don't even get to answer the questions in "hotelrecommendation.php because this Error stops me from reaching that page). But quite apart from this, I want to ask the following:

1) Do I really need the ALTER TABLE command in "processhoteldetails.php" or is this redundant?

2) In "processhoteldetails.php", I have the "ALTER TABLE Hotels ADD COLUMN" statement which adds TWO columns. BUT, in the very next line, I have "INSERT INTO Hotels VALUES" statement which has THREE columns (the extra column being the primary key SessionID). This confuses me. How can I ask the SQL machine to alter a table so that it has two columns, and then insert values into the same table with three values?? This seems completely inconsistent. Is this the reason why I am getting an error saying Session ID does not exist in field list? I really hope some of you SQL experts can shed some light on this cause no matter what I do, the Error message keeps coming up, preventing me from proceeding to the next stage.

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:sql-server]? Did you read the definition of that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't add `name` and `city` to `Hotels` because they're already in that table from your `CREATE` statement.  It's redundant as you speculated.
2. Your error makes sense because you're attempting to populate a field that doesn't exist in your table. You'll need to add the `SessionID` field before you can populate it, either in `CREATE` or `ALTER`.

It's unclear why you've got this set up in this fashion, you should probably just `CREATE` the table with all the relevant fields up front, and get rid of the multiple `ALTER` statements that add fields.

Comment: Goat, thanks so much clearing that up for me. I now understand more than I did half an hour ago.